# How to use tf.gather inside lambda function in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a model which consists of two heads, a concatenation, and a bunch of layers; all dense. However, for the concatenation I use a `Lambda` layer to not only concatenate both heads, but to also change the concatenation order for each entry in the batch using `gather`.

For this purpose I make use of an index `Input(batch_size, 512)`, and the `Lambda` layer I'm using is this:

```
Lambda(lambda x: gather(Concatenate()([x[0], x[1]])[1], x[2]))([h1, h2, idx])
```

Where `h1` is the output of the first head, `h2` is the output of the second head, and `idx` is the index tensor.

If I remove `gather` and leave only `Concatenate`, the model learns and the loss decreases. However, this way, it doesn't, and it gets stuck.

```
Concatenate()([h1, h2]) # this works well
```

Just in case, idx has a shape of (None, 512), and h1 and h2 (None, 256). Batch size is 2048.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I had to specify the batch_dims=1 parameter in gather and remove the indexing in Concatenate. So now I have this and works well:

```
Lambda(lambda x: gather(Concatenate()([x[0], x[1]]), x[2], batch_dims=1))([h1, h2, idx])
```